# Python - is it correct to check if a single value is in a column with .isin() with Pyspark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

In PySpark when I want to check if one of the values is in a column I use `.isin()`:

```
F.col('metric').isin({"Metric_value1, Metric_value2"})
```

Is it correct to perform the same check for a single value like below or there's a better way to do this?

```
F.col('metric').isin({"Metric_value1"})
```

Comment: F.col('metric')=F.lit("Metric_value1")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pyspark, `isin()` is generally used to compare a column value against multiple values and return results if any of those values matches the column value.

For a single value, you could directly use comparison operator like:

```
F.col('metric')=='Metric_value1'
```